# mysql syntax version error

Tags: mysql

I am currently trying to install a script called "phpBMS" although I encounter this error:

```
    Error Processing file 'createtables.sql' on line 43: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(14) NOT NULL,

      SQL Statement: 'CREATE TABLE menu (
      id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `uuid` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
      name varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
      link varchar(128) NOT NULL default '',
      parentid varchar(64) default '',
      displayorder int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
      createdby int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
      modifiedby int(11) default '0',
      creationdate datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
      modifieddate timestamp(14) NOT NULL,
      `roleid` VARCHAR(64),
      PRIMARY KEY  (id),
      UNIQUE KEY (`uuid`)
    ) ENGINE=INNODB ;
```

It is being mentioned that the syntax is not corresponding to my MySQL server version. I am currently using MySQL 5.5.

Does anybody have a clue on how I can get this fixed or what the correct syntax would be? Some advise would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you giving size to `timestamp`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
timestamp(14)
```

should be

```
timestamp
```

Comment: No prob. Qurious that this was in there by the way, I assumed this was from a 3rd party script.. If this is in there, there might be other hidden 'treasures' around, be warned :D